# Git commits are not updated and will not let me commit again

Tags: git, commit

I tried committing to Git and pushing to Git and Heroku. On Git, my commits are not up to date and on Heroku my builds and deploys are up to date.

I tried committing again but get this:

On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: Have you published the changes to the remote repository (i.e. `git push`)?

Comment: Yes, I've pushed to Git and Heroku master

Comment: You sure about that?  Git is disagreeing with you here.  Have you *pushed* locally?

Comment: Yeah, I signed in with my username and password. It's all local

Comment: Signing in is not the same as *pushing*.  I'm asking you if you've actually executed `git push origin master`.  That's what Git is letting you know you should do next (since your branch is ahead of `origin/master`, it'd be a good idea to push).